# Oclif prompt testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, command-line-interface, prompt, oclif

I'm attempting to write a unit test for an Oclif hook that contains a simple prompt. I want to test the output of the hook, given a 'Y' or 'N' response to the prompt.

```js
import {Hook} from '@oclif/config'
import cli from 'cli-ux'

const hook: Hook<'init'> = async function () {

  const answer = await cli.prompt("Y or N?")

  if(answer === 'Y') {
    this.log('yes')
  }
  else {
    this.log('no')
  }
}

export default hook
```

I'm using the 'fancy-test' and '@oclif/test' test frameworks described here:
https://oclif.io/docs/testing

I have tried stubbing the prompt and simulating stdin but neither are working - either the stubbed function is not available or the output is an empty string.

Here's an attempt at one test (doesn't work because 'cli.prompt is not a function'):

```js
import {expect, test} from '@oclif/test'
import cli from 'cli-ux'
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

describe('it should test the "configure telemetry" hook', () => {
  test
  .stub(cli, 'prompt', sinon.stub().resolves('Y'))
  .stdout()
  .hook('init')
  .do(output => expect(output.stdout).to.contain('yes'))
  .it()
})
```

It occurred to me that I'm probably not structuring my test properly. If anyone could point me in the right direction or provide some pseudo / sample code as to how to approach testing the above hook that would be amazing - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
import {expect, test} from '@oclif/test'
import cli from 'cli-ux'
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

describe('it should test the "configure telemetry" hook', () => {
  test
  .stub(cli, 'prompt', () => async () => 'Y')
  .stdout()
  .hook('init')
  .do(output => expect(output.stdout).to.contain('yes'))
  .it()
})
```

Stubbing with `.stub(cli, 'prompt', () => async () => 'Y')` worked for me

Comment: If you have any pointers about, how we can capture this.warn(message: string | Error) data which continues after giving warning. Thanks In advance

Comment: Just from the code snippet it's hard to tell. I kept having problem trying to log in oclif as well. Maybe you can open a separate question about it?

Comment: Does it work for multiple prompts?

Comment: You can write a function within `async (input) => { return 'Y'}` and return different values depending on what is prompted for.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to test multiple calls to `ux.prompt`, no extra libraries needed aside from the default `@oclif/core` (which is actually an extension of `fancy-test`):

Let's suppose we have a single-command-cli `Hello`, then our `src/index.ts` file would look like this:

```
import {Command, Flags, ux} from '@oclif/core'

export default class Hello extends Command {
  static description = 'describe the command here'

  static examples = [
    `$ myplugin hello
hello world from ./src/hello.ts!
`,
  ]

  static flags = {
    help: Flags.help({char: 'h'}),
    // add --version flag to show CLI version
    version: Flags.version({char: 'v'}),
  }

  interactive = async () => {
    const object = {
      email: '',
      name: '',
      phone: '',
    }

    const name = await ux.prompt('What is your name?')
    const email = await ux.prompt('What is your email?')
    const phone = await ux.prompt('What is your phone number?')

    object.name = name
    object.email = email
    object.phone = phone

    return object
  }

  async run(): Promise<void> {
    const object = await this.interactive()

    console.log(`Hello ${object.name}!`)
    console.log(`Your email is ${object.email}`)
    console.log(`Your phone number is ${object.phone}`)
  }
}
```

Our `test/index.test.tes` file will look like this:

```
import {ux} from '@oclif/core'
import {expect, test} from '@oclif/test'

import Hello from '../src/index'

const promptStub = (stub) => {
  stub.onFirstCall().resolves('John Doe') // Alias for stub.onCall(0).resolves('John Doe')
  stub.onSecondCall().resolves('john.doe@foobar.com') // Alias for stub.onCall(1).resolves('john.doe@foobar.com') 
  stub.onThirdCall().resolves('123-456-7890') // Alias for stub.onCall(2).resolves('123-456-7890')
  return stub
}

describe('basic usage', () => {
  test
    .stdout({print: true})
    .stub(ux, 'prompt', promptStub)
    .do(() => Hello.run([]))
    .it('runs hello', (ctx) => {
      expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('Hello John Doe!')
      expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('Your email is john.doe@foobar.com')
      expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('Your phone number is 123-456-7890')
    })
})
```

We need understand that `stub` is part of the [Sinon.JS](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) library, and that we can use some of the `stub` features in our `oclif` tests. Data types are specially important if we are using TypeScript.

In addition, to test multiple-command-cli's just replace `.do(() => Hello.run([]))` with the regular `.command()` calls.