# How test a user input using cli-ux prompt in oclif?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, oclif

I am creating a cli app using [oclif](https://github.com/oclif/oclif). The user executes a command, and the cli asks him if wants to continue (yes/no answer).

I trying to test the command that uses the [cli-ux prompt](https://github.com/oclif/cli-ux). I want to simulate the user interaction to enter the 'yes' word.

How can I do that?
I tried this:

```
describe('mycommand', () => {
  test
    .stdout()
    .command(['mycommand', 'action'])
    .stdin('y')
    .it('it shoud do someting', ctx => {});

});
```

Comment: This looks like a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836824/252627

Answer (score 1):

Related with [Oclif prompt testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797392/oclif-prompt-testing/56836824#56836824) I could find a solution.

Be careful how you ask the user because you can use `cli.prompt` or `cli.confirm`. In my case, I use `cli.confirm` so a possible test could be:

```js
describe('it should clean items in done list', () => {
  test
  .stub(cli, 'confirm', () => async () => 'Y')
  .stdout()
  .command(['clean', 'done'])
  .it('it shoud clean items in done list', ctx => {
    // test
  });
});
```